# How to filter commits by two (or more) authors in SourceTree?

Tags: git, svn

In Source Tree's **Search View** I can easily filer commits by *one* author this way:

1. Enter Search View with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>;
2. Choose Authors as search criteria;
3. Type the name of the author (e.g. Smith) in the bar.

It happens that I need to cherry pick commits by **2 authors** (e.g. Smith and Watson).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I filter commits by two (or more) authors?

You can use regular expressions, for example:

```
\(Smith\)\|\(Watson\)
```

Source [git - Sourcetree log commits of an author or a group of authors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38838685/3536342) answer by [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Filtering by Author Name - Adam Dymitruk](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/07/18/filtering-by-author-name/)

Comment: This does not work in Sourcetree on _Windows_.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Please try `Smith\|Watson`

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Well according to the linked answer it should work.